# Converting Firebase Realtime Database to a Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently working on a project that requires a way to pull a set of data from the databse, and then update the UI accordingly. What I'm trying to to do, is store an array in firebase, of items, then pull that to the user and have it convert back to a simple array.

My database is structured as the following;

```
database {
   master {
      itemarray: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']}}
```

[image: The data in firebase]

To pull this data, I use the following code;

```
database.ref("master/itemarray").on('value', showArray);

 function showArray(globalArray){
    console.log(globalArray.val())
    var simpleArray = Array.from(globalArray.val());
    console.log(simpleArray)
    }
 }
```

When I run this however, the array seems to break each letter into its own value, so I'm left with an array filled with letters of each 'item' instead of the entire value.

The console logs for both globalArray.val() and simple Array are below;

[image: The console logs]

Storing data in firebase with indexes, such as;

```
[0: 'item', 1: 'item2' 2: 'item3', 3: 'item4']
```

Leaves me with the same problem.

Any advice would be awesome!
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can edit your question to show: 1) How you stored the data into the database? 2) What the `console.log(globalArray.val())` prints?

Comment: Just added them. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the first line of the second screenshot it looks like your `master/itemarray` is actually a single string value, with comma separate values. It is **not** an array.

It's impossible to say why it's stored as a single string value without seeing the code that you use for writing `master/itemarray`, but based on what you shared the problem originates there.